# Find file names that don't contain a specified string

Tags: files, find

I'd like to execute the opposite of:

```
find . -name "*2013*"
```

Find all the files in the current directory that don't contain the string "2013" in their names. How can I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Simply:

```
find . ! -name '*2013*'
```

Add a `! -type d` to also exclude the files of type *directory* (like `.` itself), or `-type f` to include only *regular* files, excluding all other types of files (directories, fifos, symlinks, devices, sockets...).

Beware however that `*` matches a sequence of 0 or more **characters**. So it could report file names that contain `2013` if that `2013` was preceded or followed by something that cannot be fully decoded as valid characters in the current locale.

That can happen if you're in a locale where the characters can be encoded on more than one byte (like in UTF-8) for file names that are encoded in a different encoding. For instance, in a UTF-8 locale and a GNU system at least, it would report a `Stéphane2013` file if that `é` had been encoded in the iso8859-15 character set (as the 0xe9 byte).

Best would be to make sure the file names are encoded in the locale's character set, but if you can't guarantee it, a work around¹ is to run `find` in the C locale:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name '*2013*'
```

To exclude files that have `2013` anywhere in their path, not just their base name, though you could do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -path '*2013*'
```

It would be more efficient to do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*2013*' -prune -o -print
```

That is, tell `find` not to bother descending into the directories whose name contains `2013` (`prune`ing those parts of the tree), since we know we don't want any file in them as their path would contain `2013`.

---

<sup>¹ assuming the files are not meant to be encoded in a charset such as GB18030 or BIG5 that have hundreds of multibyte characters whose encoding ends in the encoding of `2`.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Ksh filename patterns are sufficient:

```
# files with 2013
ls -d -- *2013*

# files without 2013
ls -d -- !(*2013*)
```

[Reference](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#File%20Name%20Generation)

If your shell is bash, you need to run `shopt -s extglob` before you can use this pattern (you can put it in your `.bashrc`). If your shell is zsh, you need to run `setopt ksh_glob` (you can put it in your `.zshrc`). Zsh also offers `ls -d -- ^*2013*`, which requires a preliminary `setopt extended_glob`.

Depending on what you're doing with these filenames, `ls` may not be the right command to use. To store them in an array

```
filenames=( !(*2013*) )
for f in "${filenames[@]}"; do ...; done
```

Comment: That doesn't recurse in subdirectories and will skip dot files though (and `ls` will return an error message if the pattern doesn't match any file). Also note that `ksh` will sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to find `!` is to pipe `egrep` using `-v` option, which invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines:

```bsh
find . | egrep -v 2013
```

Here the advantage is to use all the power of egrep to filter your output the way you like.

Comment: That only works if you can guarantee file paths won't contain newline characters. Note that several `find` implementations now have a `-regex` predicate to match file paths using regular expressions.

Comment: Also note that it excludes any file  that has `2013` anywhere in its path, not only in its (base) name.

Answer (score -1):

Find all files in current directory that does not contain a certain string, here "2013":

```
find . ! -name "*2013*" -type f
```

Comment: This is essentially the same thing as http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102614/117549 from 3 years ago, except you've added "-f" which makes this a worse answer.